# Is it possible to use latin character in comments of t4 template?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, templates, t4

I'm trying to create a portuguese comments in a t4 template of the Add Controller in my project.

The comments in t4 template:

```
/// <summary>
/// Controller que trata as requisições de pesquisa, inclusão, alteração e exclusão de <#= mvcHost.ControllerName.Replace("Controller", "") #>.
/// </summary>
```

The problem is when i add a controller, the comments appear like this:

```
/// <summary>
/// Controller que trata as requisi��es de pesquisa, inclus�o, altera��o e exclus�o de Teste.
/// </summary>
```

Obs: The square � is the black "? diamond" symbol.

So, how can i use latin characteres in a t4 template?

My Template:

```
<#@ template language="C#" HostSpecific="True" #>
<#@ output extension=".cs" encoding="UTF-8" #> 
<#
MvcTextTemplateHost mvcHost = (MvcTextTemplateHost)(Host);
#>
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace <#= mvcHost.Namespace #>
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Controller que trata as requisições de pesquisa, inclusão, alteração e exclusão de <#= mvcHost.ControllerName.Replace("Controller", "") #>.
    /// </summary>
    public class <#= mvcHost.ControllerName #> : Controller
    {
         // The class code
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to specify the encoding explicitly for the output of your templates:

```
<#@ output extension=".cs" encoding="UTF-8" #>
```

**Edit**: Your code works correctly on mine (after removing the `mvcHost` parts).

Try resaving both your template and its output file as UTF-8 by performing this procedure for each:

1. Open it in Visual Studio
2. Click File, Save As…
3. Choose Save with Encoding… (see below)
4. Make sure that UTF-8 is selected
5. Click OK

[image]
[image]

Comment: Would it be possible for you to post your template as part of your question?

Comment: Thank you! So, one last doubt, you said: "Your code works correctly on mine (after removing the mvcHost parts).". Why "after removing the mvcHost parts"? I don't remove these parts, and it works...

Comment: Glad it worked :-) Don’t worry about my `mvcHost` remark; I guess I had a missing reference in my project.

Answer (score 0):

Try to write the characters like this

```
inclus&atilde;o
```

See a table of HTML codes [here](http://webdesign.about.com/library/bl_htmlcodes.htm).

Comment: Yes, but since this is a doc-comment, you have to use this special syntax anyway. In the generated help document the comments should appear correctly. You have to use `&lt;` and `&gt;` as well for `<` and `>` in doc-comments.

Comment: XML does not innately forbid non-ASCII Unicode. It should not be strictly necessary to use character entity references in place of the characters. (XML syntax such as `<`, `>`, and `&` does not count.)

Comment: How do you reference a DTD to import entity references into the XML docs?