# Use Unicode in T4 Templates

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, templates, unicode, t4

I have some Persian characters in T4 templates, but all of them show up as `?`. I use template - generator and this is my script to use generator:

```
<#@ template language="C#v4" hostspecific="True" debug="True" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Core" #>
<#@ output extension=".cs" encoding="UTF8" #>
<#@ include file="T4Toolbox.tt" #>
<#@ include file="AllGenerator.tt" #>
<#
    AllGenerator generator = new AllGenerator();
    generator.DatabaseName = "MyDatabase";
    generator.Run();
#>
```

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9008611/is-it-possible-to-use-latin-character-in-comments-of-t4-template) I must save with Unicode, but I can't do it. When I select `Save as`, the `Save Type as` option is just `T4 Editor (*.tbx)` and there is no option to save with Unicode. Like this:

[image]

So how can I use Persian characters in T4? Is there any problem on my side?

Comment: it's `UTF-8` not `UTF8`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a bug in the T4 editor add-on that you're using.  You could try uninstalling that temporarily.

Comment: I uninstall and install it again, every thing worked fine, thanks